# Animation doesn't play while coroutine is running

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, loading, coroutine

When my scene starts, I start a coroutine that generates a puzzle which is displayed to the user. Sometimes, this generation can take a few seconds but usually quite fast. Because the user can also refresh the puzzle from the scene, I don't want to jump back and forth to a separate loading scene and instead just show a simple animation while the coroutine is running. I've tested two animations on the same sprite: an Animator of the sprite and a simple rotation on update. However, like the title says both of these aren't running while the coroutine is running. I can see that that animation works because after the coroutine finishes, both animations begin (see that SetActive(false) commented out below). How can I get this animation to work?

The structure is like this:

-Game Scene

--Canvas

---PuzzleControl Game Object (with PuzzleControl script)

----animation Game Object (with Sprite Renderer and Animator components)

---LoadingScreen Game Object (with LoadingAnimation script)

```
public class PuzzleControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    private PuzzleBuilder builder;
    void Start()
    {
        builder = this.gameObject.AddComponent<PuzzleBuilder>();
        LoadingScreen.SetActive(true);
        StartCoroutine(builder.Refresh());
    }

    public void RebuildPuzzle()
    {
        LoadingScreen.SetActive(true);
        StartCoroutine(builder.Refresh());
    }

    public void BuildComplete()
    {
        // This will be called by our builder -- currently turned off
        //LoadingScreen.SetActive(false);
    }
}


public class LoadingAnimation : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject animation;
    private float rotateSpeed = 200f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        animation.GetComponent<Transform>().Rotate(new Vector3(0f,0f, rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common misconception, coroutines don't actually run on a seperate thread so if you have a lot of computation to do you need to move it into a Task and run it on the thread pool otherwise Unity will still freeze while it's doing this work. Coroutines only return control of the cpu when they yield, each frame unity will re-enter the coroutine where it left off which gives the illusion of the code running at the same time when really it's just being sliced into chunks using the yield keyword.

A limitation of moving things into a thread is that as a general rule, you cant actually touch anything that is part of the Unity engine, so you will need to collect the data you need, then send it off to a thread for calculation and then apply the changes to the scene when it's finished.

Here is a quick example on how to send a long running calculation so a seperate thread (or at least parallelise it, as C# will send it to a ThreadPool to handle distribution):

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

void Start()
{   
    // send it 
    var taskHandle = Task<MapBuildData>.Run(DoLongBuildCalculation).ContinueWith(OnBuildComplete);
}

MapBuildData DoLongBuildCalculation()
{
    // do long calculation.
    return result;
}

void OnBuildComplete(Task<MapBuildData> buildTask)
{
    if(buildTask.IsFaulted || buildTask.IsCanceled)
    {
        // handle it.
    }

    // do something in with buildTask.Result
}
```

EDIT: For clarification, you should not interact with Unity objects inside of DoLongBuildCalculation().

Comment: Thanks for this explanation.  Unfortunately, my builder is creating game objects so this won't work for my situation.  Perhaps the animation can somehow put into a separate thread?

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't possible. My recommendation is to just save a list of where you want to spawn objects after it's finished and send that back to the main thread. If your map build process relies on responding to things like overlaps in the engine then I'm afraid you're out of luck.

Comment: You could of course break your build steps up into smaller more manageable chunks and yield control back to the engine. So if you iterated over 1000 objects, every 50 or so you yield and that gives the CPU time to update the animation.

Comment: Thanks!  That was the tip I needed.  I had a particular heavy piece that was causing the delay, adding a yield return in inside loop actually caused the whole process to take a major performance hit while my animation ran happily.  I was able to make a compromise by putting my yield in the outside loop.  Now I get a jerky animation and decent load times.  Not perfect but I can work on it from here.  For now I'm happy with the result and I have a better understanding of coroutines thanks to you.

Comment: Glad to help! It's definitely one of those things that once you get your head around opens up a whole new understanding :)